# Jmeter 3.0 Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement)

Tags: jmeter

[image][image]

I am using Oracle DB from Jmeter and I am running Select statement with a very small query, I am getting below error

[image]

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement)

Answer (score 0):

You change the default values, and most important you define zero time to wait for connection. so you can't create connection.

Set [Max Wait](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to a valid value as 10000

> Max Wait (ms) Pool throws an error if the timeout period is exceeded in the process of trying to retrieve a connection

Also I'm not sure about your validation query, for Oracle it should be

```
Select 1 from dual
```

> Validation Query A simple query used to determine if the database is still responding. This defaults to the 'isValid()' method of the jdbc driver, which is suitable for many databases. However some may require a different query; for example Oracle something like 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL' could be used.

Comment: I have tried with validation query select * from dual; but got same result

Comment: Did you changed the nax wait?

Comment: @Umesh Kumar remove `;` from select statement

Comment: @Umesh Kumar change Transaction Isolation to Default

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `getData` from the "Validation Query" and replace it with [`select 1 from dual`](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2769)

Also consider upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) on next available opportunity as according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the last available JMeter version, newer JMeter versions normally contain bug fixes, new features and performance improvements so it might be the case you're suffering from a bug which has already been addressed.